# jquery animate not working on first click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement Read More button with animation. **Animation working fine after the first click but on the first click, it seems that the animation method doesn't come into consideration.**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jp9573/Lg0avkuw) link for the below code.

Here is my code:

```js
var text = $('.content')
const originalHeight = text.height();

$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
  var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
  var fullHeight = text[0].scrollHeight;

  if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
    linkText = "Show less";
    $content.addClass('showContent').removeClass('hideContent');
    text.animate({
      'height': fullHeight
    });
  } else {
    linkText = "Show more";
    $content.addClass('hideContent').removeClass('showContent');
    text.animate({
      'height': originalHeight
    });
  };

  $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
div.text-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  text-align: justify;
}

.show-more {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the sake of SEO you're probably better of showing the content first and then hiding using jq on page load, this will also probably fix the animate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
var text = $('.content')
const originalHeight = text.height();

//======================
//add this line

 text.css("height",originalHeight );

//======================


$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
  var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
  var fullHeight = text[0].scrollHeight;

  if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
    linkText = "Show less";
    $content.addClass('showContent').removeClass('hideContent');
    text.animate({
      'height': fullHeight
    });
  } else {
    linkText = "Show more";
    $content.addClass('hideContent').removeClass('showContent');
    text.animate({
      'height': originalHeight
    });
  };

  $this.text(linkText);
});
```

```css
div.text-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  text-align: justify;
}

.show-more {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct because showContent class has height:auto, and it needs to have a determinate height for make the animation, and that line gives a determinate height via javascript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `===` is a case sensitive comparison. Your code is `if (linkText === "SHOW MORE")`  where your main text is **Show more**. Thats all.